# Does prometheus source_labels can only be labels start with "__"?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Is it possible to create a label using the labels that are not start with `__`?

Backgroud:
I'm working with prometheus and I'm trying to monitor the lvs serivce using `node_exporter`, So I need a label called `vrrp_vs`(vrrp virtualserver), it should contains a vip and a port, such as `172.16.10.10:80`, I tried to make a leble myself using two lables `local_address` and `local_port` of the metric `node_ipvs_backend_connections_active`, but it got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution at last with the help of my leader.

[`relabel_configs`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#<relabel_config>) does only works on the meta labels start with `__` before **scrape** action. But,
[`metric_relabel_configs`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#<metric_relabel_configs>) can do the trick.

**metric_relabel_configs** will modfify the metric after scraped and before stored in prometheus. This is really amazing!
Below is what I did.

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [local_address, local_port]
    action: replace
    regex: '(.+);(.+)'
    target_label: virtualserver
    #separator: ':'
    replacement: $1:$2
```

`regex: '(.+);(.+)'` means if both `local_address` and `local_port` exist then combine them into one string with seperator `;` . `replacement: $1:$2` means replace them with 
`local_address:local_port` format.

The result:
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use PromQL [label_join](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_join()) to create a combined label from existing labels.

```
label_join(node_ipvs_backend_connections_active, "vrrp_vs", "local_address", ":", "local_port")
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already did this before, but the new label only shows in the new metric, not other metrics, so this isn't what I want.